# Devise CustomFailure and mount in routes, bad redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, sidekiq

I'm using a `CustomFailure` class like shown in the doc ([here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated)) to redirect to our sign in page when someone is unauthenticated:

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
  include Localization

  def redirect_url
    url_for(controller: "/public/sessions", action: :new, locale: locale_to_params(I18n.locale))
  end

  # You need to override respond to eliminate recall
  def respond
    if http_auth?
      http_auth
    else
      redirect
    end
  end
end
```

So this normally redirects to `http://www.acmecorp.com/en/signin`, but with the Sidekiq panel in `routes.rb`:

```
  authenticate :user, lambda { |u| u.super_admin? } do
    require "sidekiq/web"
    mount Sidekiq::Web => "/sidekiq"
  end
```

I get redirected to `http://www.acmecorp.com/sidekiq/en/signin` instead of `http://www.acmecorp.com/en/signin`. Any reason why the redirect does not get rid of the `/sidekiq` part?

Thanks!